# Stop Mosquitto from sending the message to its owner(sender)

Tags: mqtt, publish-subscribe, mosquitto

At the moment mosquitto send the received message to whoever that is subscribed to the topic, even the sender of the message. Is it possible to stop the mosquitto from sending the message to its owner?

Comment: Subscribing a client to the same topic which it is publishing, and then not wanting to receive it, is a weird design indeed. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: why should the publisher receives his own message? whats the point of receiving your own message? the publisher is subscribed to that topic to receive others publications and not his own.

Comment: Because that is what the subscriber asked for, by subscribing to the topic you get ALL messages on that topic.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy straightforward solution to this. However it is possible with Mosquitto broker. I needed to download the source code and change the underlying codes and compile it again. It requires moderate knowledge of C programming. I need to study the code behind the broker and understand how it works. A bit hard and time consuming but possible.

Comment: Right, so you've changed the broker to violate the spec. My answer still stands

Comment: Not yet. seems like a hard job. I am still studying how the broker works. Yes you can change the source code and change the standard settings and normal behavior of the broker since it is opensource.

Answer (score 3):

If using MQTT v5.0, you can set the `No Local` flag at subscription time for the subscription option. This flag tells the broker not to send an application message received with a client ID to a subscriber with the same client ID, which is exactly what you are expecting here.

This is not available in MQTT v3.1.1 unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is the correct behaviour according to the MQTT spec

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15091036)

Comment: The question was "is it possible to stop this from happening" And this is the answer

Comment: I know that is how it should behave. My question was, is it possible to change that behavior?

Comment: My comment was directed at the person voting to close this answer as not an answer. No, that behaviour can not be changed

Comment: Just found answer to my question. It is indeed possible with Mosquitto broker.  Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @ShahabIntezari write the found answer here please. Share the knowledge. Self answering (and self selecting) is legal and correct.